# How to copy photos/files with the same name but different extension to another folder?

Tags: windows, script

In Windows OS, I have two folders:

1. All raw photos with `*.CR2` and `*.ARW` extensions
2. `*.JPG` (JPEG) photos that are picked by the client

In this case, I would like to detect/select all raw photos (`Folder 1`) with the same file name with the client-picked photos (`Folder 2`) and copy them to a separate folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like the client is cherry picking the low res JPG files after viewing them and would like you to then process the high resolution versions. Its worth also noting to perhaps let the client know that the CR2 and ARW files can be easily viewed within free software IrfhanView. That way they can make their selections from the high res stuff instead.

Answer (score 2):

Read over [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and look into using for
 loop for the task such as:

```
 for %a in ("C:\Folder 1\*.cr2") do (
         if exist "D:\Folder 2\%~Na.jpg" xcopy /f /y "%~a" "D:\Folder 3\"
 )
```

or a similar variation as such that suffices for your needs, read over that link and learn while you are at it.