# How to get and copy all files that have the same file name but different extension name using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, copy

I've been trying to filter out my RAW images(.ARW) from my SONY camera to my PC and was thinking to do it by viewing all .JPG images and deleting other .JPG images I do not like.
Once I get the chose .JPG images I wanted to use them to find all the RAW files which are the counterpart of the .JPG files I have chosen.

I thought I was close but I think something is wrong.

```
$ext_FindName = "JPG"

$source_Path = "c:\Pictures\SONY\RAWandJPG"
$dest_Path = "c:\temp\chosenRAW"

 Get-ChildItem -Path $source_Path -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Where-Object { $_.extension -eq '.'+$ext_GetName -AND (Test-Path "$($_.BaseName).$ext_FindName") } | Copy-Item -Destination $dest_Path

pause
```

[How to copy photos/files with the same name but different extension to another folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1331853/how-to-copy-photos-files-with-the-same-name-but-different-extension-to-another-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a JPG file has a match with the RAW extension in the `RAWandJPG` folder, the RAW will be copied to the `chosenRaw` folder. This does assume that there are not more than 2 files with the same (e.g. 1.jpg,1.raw)

```
$source_Path = "c:\Pictures\SONY\RAWandJPG"
$dest_Path = "c:\temp\chosenRAW"
$include = "*.jpg","*.raw"

$files = Get-ChildItem $source_Path -Include $include -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | group Basename 

foreach($group in $groups)
{ 
    if ($group.Count -eq 2)
    {
       foreach($file in $group.group)
       {
            if(($file.name).Contains('.raw')) 
            { 
                Copy-Item $file.fullname $dest_Path
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this!! :) actually I noticed something was missing from your earlier post and your edited post looks better and similar to the one I made based on your code...I have not tested this new one anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me out @Narzard. I have created a script similar to what you have shared but not sure if mine is efficient but it also does its job...

```
## INPUT DETAILS
$source_Path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter source path'
$dest_Path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter destination path'

$ext_GetName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter extension name of RAW file (default: ARW)'
if(-not($ext_GetName)){
    $ext_GetName = 'ARW'
}
elseif($ext_GetName.Length -ge 4){
    Write-output "Extension name is not compatible, make sure you are typing the input max of 3 characters only."
    $ext_GetName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter extension name of RAW file (default: ARW)'
}


$ext_FindName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter extension name of compressed pictures (default: JPG)'
if(-not($ext_FindName)){
    $ext_FindName = 'JPG'
}
elseif($ext_FindName.Length -ge 4){
    Write-output "Extension name is not compatible, make sure you are typing the input max of 3 characters only."
    $ext_FindName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter extension name of compressed pictures (default: JPG)'
}



## IF YOU WANT TO USE STATIC DETAILS
## -------------------#

## EXTENSION NAMES
#$ext_GetName = "CR2"
#$ext_FindName = "JPG"
## PATH
#$source_Path = "F:\Pictures\FAMILY, LOVE, FRIENDS, TRAVEL PHOTOS\_Photo Archives\2022-11-28 (AYALA LIGHTS)"
#$dest_Path = "c:\temp\test"
## -------------------#

$ext_GetName_incl = "*."+$ext_GetName
$ext_FindName_incl = "*."+$ext_FindName

$RAWfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $source_Path -Include $ext_GetName_incl -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$COMPfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $source_Path -Include $ext_FindName_incl -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

write-host "Looking for "$ext_GetName" files for chosen "$ext_FindName" files in "$source_Path

##FOR TESTING## Get-ChildItem -Path $source_Path -Include $ext_xxxxx_xxx -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$counter=0
foreach( $RAWfile in $RAWfiles ) 
{
    foreach( $COMPfile in $COMPfiles ) 
    {   
        if(($RAWfile.BaseName -eq $COMPfile.BaseName)) 
        { 
            write-host Successfully copied $RAWfile.name 
            Copy-Item $RAWfile.fullname $dest_Path
            $counter++
        }
    }
}

write-host Successfully copied $counter files to $dest_Path
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use two separate `Get-ChildItem` lines for this.

The first to recieve an array of all .JPG BaseNames found and the second one using a `Where-Object` clause to get all .ARW files that have a BaseName we can match with one of the BaseNames in the first aray.

```
$sourcePath  = "F:\Pictures\FAMILY, LOVE, FRIENDS, TRAVEL PHOTOS\_Photo Archives\2022-11-28 (AYALA LIGHTS)"
$destination = "c:\temp\test"

# make sure the destination path exists before copying/moving files to it
$null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force

# get the .JPG (sometimes also .JPEG) files list as array of BaseNames
# if you do not have .JPEG extensions, use the more efficient
# -Filter '*.JPG' instead of -Include '*.jpg', '*.jpeg'
$jpegs = (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Include '*.jpg', '*.jpeg' -File -Recurse).BaseName

# next get all the raw files (extension .ARW) that have .jpg counterparts and copy them
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.arw' -File -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $jpegs -contains $_.BaseName } |
Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```